# Datos en tablas html + mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Espero puedan ayudarme con la siguiente situación:

Estoy trabajando con una sencilla tabla en html en la cual debo pintar los registros que extraiga de la Base de Datos que previamente fue elaborada. En ella trato de traer los registros de fechas, todo va bien cuando se trata de un solo registro ya que al mostrarlos en la tabla ocupa la posición correcta en cada columna, el problema que presento es cuando son mas de un registro ya que este me lo coloca fuera de la tabla y sin diseño.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si exista una forma en la que la tabla se incremento en dado caso que exista más de un registro.

El código que estoy manejando es el siguiente:

```
  <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered text-center" id="tabladinamicaloadEnero">
          <td></td>
          <td class="tdFec_cont">
            CONTACTO
          </td>
          <td class="tdFec_entr">
            ENTREVISTA
          </td>
          <td class="tdFec_eva">
            EVALUACIÓN
          </td>
          <td class="tdFec_ventC">
            VENTA DE CARRERA
          </td>
          <td class="tdFec_ind">
            INDUCCIÓN
          </td>
          <td class="tdFec_cone">
            CONEXIÓN
          </td>
          <td class="tdFec_pros">
            PROSPECTO
          </td>
          </tr>
          <?php
          $sql = "SELECT nombre, fecha_contacto, fecha_cita, fecha_evaluacion, fecha_ventaCarrera, fecha_induccion, fecha_conexion, fechareg, fec2, fec3, fec4, fec5 FROM llenado_formulario WHERE edat = '$edat' AND fec5 BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-31' AND conexion LIKE '%i%'";
          $resultT = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
          while ($conexiones = mysqli_fetch_array($resultT)) {
          ?>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdEncab_fecEdat">
                Fecha EDAT
              </td>
              <td class="tdResult_fec">
                <?= $contactoEdat = $conexiones['fecha_contacto'] ?>
              </td>
              <td class="tdResult_fec">
                <?= $citaEdat = $conexiones['fecha_cita'] ?>
              </td>
              <td class="tdResult_fec">
                <?= $evaluacionEdat = $conexiones['fecha_evaluacion'] ?>
              </td>
              <td class="tdResult_fec">
                <?= $ventaCEdat = $conexiones['fecha_ventaCarrera'] ?>
              </td>
              <td class="tdResult_fec">
                <?= $induccionEdat = $conexiones['fecha_induccion'] ?>
              </td>
              <td class="tdResult_fec">
                <?= $conexionEdat = $conexiones['fecha_conexion'] ?>
              </td>
              <td rowspan=2 class="nombreProsp">
                <?= $prospectoEdat = $conexiones['nombre'] ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="tdEncab_fecSis">
                Fecha Sistema
              </td>
              <td class="tdResult_fec">
                <?php
                $contactoSis = $conexiones['fechareg'];
                $newDate_ConSis = date_create($contactoSis);
                $fecha = date_format($newDate_ConSis, 'Y-m-d');
                echo $fecha;
                ?>
              </td>
              <td class="tdResult_fec">
                <?= $citaSis = $conexiones['fecha_cita'] ?>
              </td>
              <td class="tdResult_fec">
                <?= $evaluacionSis = $conexiones['fec2'] ?>
              </td>
              <td class="tdResult_fec">
                <?= $ventaCSis = $conexiones['fec3'] ?>
              </td>
              <td class="tdResult_fec">
                <?= $induccionSis = $conexiones['fec4'] ?>
              </td>
              <td class="tdResult_fec">
                <?= $conexionSis = $conexiones['fec5']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: No necesitas hacer tantas consultas, hazlo en una sola con `SELECT *` y usa un ciclo (ej. `while`); revisa los [ejemplos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) de la documentación.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, en cuestión de lo que me indicas lo trate de hacer pero fue algo que no me resulto como esperaba y volví a lo rustico que era hacerlo de esta forma.

Comment: Con el código de tu intento -con while- es mucho mas probable que llegue la ayuda.

Comment: Ok, volveré a retomar la parte del código que había realizado con el while y vuelvo a modificar.

Comment: @Sal hice la corrección metiendo lo mencionado en un while, solo que el problema que se presenta ahora es que si me trae los demás registros pero los marca fuera de la tabla.

Comment: Cuando usas la etiqueta corta de eco, no es necesaria la asignación, basta usar: `<?= $conexiones['fecha_cita'] ?>`.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137969/discussion-between-sal-and-nancy).